How can the doctor measure out a dose (dissolved in water) of exactly 10% of a tablet?
A doctor must measure out a precise fraction of a tablet for a young patient.  The doctor has an empty 5-ounce vial, an empty 3-ounce vial, a water supply, a sink, and a single water-soluble tablet.
How can the doctor measure out a dose (dissolved in water) of exactly 10% of a tablet?

Attribution:  momath.org

A good doctor won't use imperial measurement units to start with.

The current answers treat the tablet's volume and mass as negligible - dissolving a tablet in X ounces of water is considered to produce X ounces of solution. Is this intended?

@user2357112 : I had same concern but I guess one can ignore X+tablet=X detail, unless OP has a comment

@user2357112 Let’s assume that dissolving the tablet in water does not increase the volume of that water.  In other words, if a vial contains X ounces of water and then the tablet is added then afterwards there will still be X ounces of liquid in that vial.

It's realistic for dissolving a small amount of soluble compound in water not to affect the volume of the water. In some cases, dissolving a solid in water can even reduce the overall volume.

Sometimes percentage water does mater exactly though... Like in potato paradox.

There may be an easier way to do this, but in a pinch this will work:
Step 1: Measure 1 ounce of water

 fill the 3-vial with water, pour it all into the 5-vial, refill the 3-vial, pour until 5-vial is full. There's now 1 ounce of water left in the 3-vial

Step 2: Dissolve the pill into the 1 ounce of water.
Step 3: Remove 75% of the medicine

 Empty the 5-vial, pour the 1 oz with 100% medicine into the 5-vial, fill the 3-vial from the water supply, pour that 3 oz of water into the 5-vial, and mix well. Now there's 100% of the medicine in 4oz of water. Pour 3 oz of it into the 3-vial (and discard), leaving 1 oz of water and 25% of the medicine in the 5-vial.

Step 4: Remove three fifths of the remaining medicine

 Top up the 5-vial with water, mix well. Now there's 5 ounces of water with 25% of the medicine in the 5-vial. Then pour 3 oz into the 3-vial.

This removes three fifths of the medicine, leaving exactly the desired 10% of the medicine dissolved in the 2 oz of water in the 5 oz vial.

The trick is to start by

 dissolving the tablet in four ounces of water. This can be achieved by filling the five-ounce vial, emptying into the three-ounce vial, dumping out the three-ounce vial and pouring in the rest of the five-ounce vial, then refilling the five-ounce vial and topping off the three-ounce vial.


 Dump out the three-ounce vial, then refill it from the five-ounce vial and dump those three ounces out as well, leaving one ounce of water containing 25% of a tablet. Top off the five-ounce vial with water, and pour it into the three-ounce vial, leaving behind two ounces of water containing 10% of a tablet.


I figured out the trick, but was too late. My solution would just be a worse version of yours.

Here's a solution with the minimal number of steps:



action
3-ounce water
3-ounce dosage
5-ounce water
5-ounce dosage




fill $3$
XXX
$0$
.....
$0$


add tablet to $3$
XXX
$1$
.....
$0$


pour $3$ into $5$
...
$0$
XXX..
$1$


fill $3$
XXX
$0$
XXX..
$1$


pour $3$ into $5$
X..
$0$
XXXXX
$1$


pour $5$ into $3$
XXX
$\frac{2}{5}$
XXX..
$\frac{3}{5}$


pour $3$ into $5$
X..
$\frac{2}{15}$
XXXXX
$\frac{13}{15}$


dump $5$
X..
$\frac{2}{15}$
.....
$0$


pour $3$ into $5$
...
$0$
X....
$\frac{2}{15}$


fill $3$
XXX
$0$
X....
$\frac{2}{15}$


pour $3$ into $5$
...
$0$
XXXX.
$\frac{2}{15}$


pour $5$ into $3$
XXX
$\frac{1}{10}$
X....
$\frac{1}{30}$



AxiomaticSystem's solution (also optimal)



action
3-ounce water
3-ounce dosage
5-ounce water
5-ounce dosage




fill $5$
...
$0$
XXXXX
$0$


pour $5$ into $3$
XXX
$0$
XX...
$0$


dump $3$
...
$0$
XX...
$0$


pour $5$ into $3$
XX.
$0$
.....
$0$


fill $5$
XX.
$0$
XXXXX
$0$


pour $5$ into $3$
XXX
$0$
XXXX.
$0$


add tablet to $5$
XXX
$0$
XXXX.
$1$


dump $3$
...
$0$
XXXX.
$1$


pour $5$ into $3$
XXX
$\frac{3}{4}$
X....
$\frac{1}{4}$


dump $3$
...
$0$
X....
$\frac{1}{4}$


fill $5$
...
$0$
XXXXX
$\frac{1}{4}$


pour $5$ into $3$
XXX
$\frac{3}{20}$
XX...
$\frac{1}{10}$




Do all other previously given answers need more steps?

I count 13 steps for Bass's solution, 12 steps for Tom Sirgedas's solution, and 11 steps for  AxiomaticSystem, but I may have miscounted.

AxiomaticSystem's solution is also 12 steps -- I added a table to show it

Oh, I forgot the "add a tablet" step, thanks!

I counted same numbers. But preferred some double checks from  people involved :)
